# How to make an efficient program that test very large amounts of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I need to write a program that takes an input with ones an zeroes and tries to find the longest consecutive series of zeroes uninterrupted by ones. (I have managed to code that part). The problem comes when I need to find in the list of 1's and 0's which 1's I could replace with 0's to make the series of consecutive 0's the longest with g replacements allowed.

I am having trouble writing this mathematically which would be useful for transferring it to code. I have already written the program that finds the longest series of consecutive 0's I just am not able to code the second part; here is what I have already made.

```
# Get File Ready To Read
with open("/Users/yannkull/Desktop/marathon-sub3-attempt1.txt", "r") as f:
    current_line = f.readlines()


x = 2 
while x < 202:
    temp_list = []

    for a in current_line[x]:  # Format Line With Data
        if a != ' ':
            temp_list.append(a)
    temp_list.remove(temp_list[len(temp_list) - 1])

    k = int(current_line[x - 1])  # Recieve info line that tells us how many characters we have 

    a = 0
    sums = []
    while a < k:  # Find the longest consecutive series of zeroes in one line 

        somme = 0
        while temp_list[a] == '0':

            somme += 1
            a += 1

            if a == k:
                break

        sums.append(somme)  # Add the result to a list 
        a += 1

    print("Case #", int(x / 2 - 1), ": ", max(sums), sep='')  # Print the largest result for each case

    x += 2
```

I just really have no clue how to implement the problem I have been given into my code so if someone could give me a few pointers that would be great.
I am open to using numpy I just don't know how it would be useful in this situation. I just don't think my PC would handle solving this by brute force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the brute force by assuming that all replaced values should be "consecutive":

If you're trying to replace exactly two 0's into 1's in order to get the longest sequence of 1's in this input:

> 111010100101110

You will most likely test:

> 111X1X100101110

(`X` means you try to replace a 0 with a 1)

but not

> 111X101001X1110

as there is no point in replacing 0's if there are still 0's in between.

This greatly reduces the number of possible replacement possibilities.